# Execute commands one by one in .aliases file in bash

Tags: bash, shell, alias

I would like to create an alias in bash where if I type 'logs' it should take me to the latest log file. My folder is structured such that ~/logs/date/time. After googling for sometime I found out the below command and it is working fine if i give in the bash prompt

```
cd ~/logs && cd `ls -tr | tail -1` && cd `ls -tr | tail -1`
```

But if I add it .aliases and map it to 'logs' then it is not working as expected. It cd's into logs and then try cd into latest file/folder where i execute the command. (For eg.) if I am in FOLDER1 and execute 'logs', it 
cd's into logs and then try to cd into latest folder in FOLDER1.

Edited: My alias definition

```
alias logs="cd ~/logs && cd `ls -tr | tail -1` && cd `ls -tr | tail -1`"
```

Any idea why it is behaving like this & how can I make this work ?

Comment: Aside: `ls -t` is **not** a safe way to find newest/oldest available files. See [ParsingLs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), and [BashFAQ #3](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/003).

Comment: ...this code will work very badly if the selected file in your log directory has spaces in its name, much less more exotic characters such as newlines.

Comment: BTW, if you showed *your alias definition itself*, that would be helpful. It's obvious from the problem that you're using double-quotes rather than single-quotes, but we wouldn't have to infer it if it were shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that backquoted commands are evaluated at once when defining the alias.

Either escape them:

```
alias logs="cd ~/logs && cd \`ls -tr | tail -1\` && cd \`ls -tr | tail -1\`"
```

Or single quote the expression as Charles commented (you cannot use env. variables here):

```
alias logs='cd ~/logs && cd "`ls -tr | tail -1`" && cd "`ls -tr | tail -1`"'
```

Or create a function, that works too and is more readable, so you can add robustness more easily as Charles (again!) suggested (when creating an alias, you just do a quick & hack job):

```
logs()
{ 
     cd ~/logs || return
     cd "`ls -tr | tail -1`" || return
     cd "`ls -tr | tail -1`" || return
}
```

Comment: Also, consider putting `|| return`s on all your `cd`s, such that we don't try to go into a subdirectory of the current directory if `cd ~/logs` fails for some reason.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: the reason: old habits die hard when you started on ksh. Edited with your comments.

Comment: (Adding more quotes would also reduce the number of places where this failed due to `ls -tr | tail -1`'s inadequacies).

Comment: *shrug*. Biggest data loss incident I've been witness to was one where a log directory had a new program writing into it that had a buffer overflow that dumped random garbage into a filename; the script responsible for pruning old backups didn't quote adequately, and one day the garbage happened to include a whitespace-surrounded `*`. Those logs were used for customer billing. Better to be in good habits when it doesn't matter than mess up when it does.

Comment: yeah, also funny: `cd /tmpx; rm -rf *` => `-bash: cd: /tmpx: No such file or directory` but why does it take so long to get the prompt ? :)

Comment: BTW, you could also use single quotes in the alias definition to reduce the amount of quoting that needs to be added.

Comment: I tried this logs()
    { 
         cd ~/logs || return
         cd "`ls -tr | tail -1`" || return
         cd "`ls -tr | tail -1`" || return
    }

-bash: ~/.aliases: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
-bash: ~/.aliases: line 1: `logs()'

Comment: @aswin, can't tell if that's right or not without seeing the whitespace, and `&&`s are just as good as `|| return` here. Consider using semicolons: `logs() { cd ~/logs && cd "$(ls -tr | tail -1)" && cd "$(ls -tr | tail -1)"; }`

Comment: Also, unalias `logs` before defining `logs` as a function because old alias expands :) (just happened to me). Make your pick :)